# How can I change the text-coding of my Java Programm?

Tags: java, windows, utf-8

I have a Java-Programm, which I develop with Netbeans.
I changed the settings on Netbeans, so that it will understand UTF-8.

But if I clean, and build my Programm and use it with my Windows System, the textcoding changes and letters like: "ü", "ä", and "ö" aren't displayed and used properly anymore.

How can I communicate with my OS and tell him to use UTF-8?

Or is there any good workaround?

EDIT: Sry for beeing so unspecific.
Well, first of all: I use Docx4j and the Apache POI with the getText() Methods to get some Texts from doc, docx, and pdf's and save them in a String.

Then Im trying to match Keywords within those texts, that I read out of an .txt file.

Those Keywords are displayed in a Combobox in the runnable Java-file.
I can see the encoding problems there. It wont match any of Keywords using the words described above.

In my IDE its working fine.
Im trying to post some code here, after I redesign it.

TXT-File is in UTF-8. If I convert it ti ANSI I see the same Problems like in the Jar.
reading out of it:

```
  if(inputfile.exists() && inputfile.canRead())
            {
                try {

                    FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputfilepath);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    String zeile = null;

                    while ((zeile = in.readLine()) != null) {

                       while(zeile.startsWith("#"))
                       {
                           if (zeile.startsWith(KUERZELTITEL)) {
                               int cut = zeile.indexOf('=');

                               zeile = zeile.substring(cut, zeile.length());
                               eingeleseneTagzeilen.put(KUERZELTITEL, zeile.substring(1));
                               kuerzel = zeile.substring(1);
                           }
```

...

this did it for me:

```
                        File readfile   = new File(inputfilepath);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(readfile), "UTF8"));
```

Thx!

Comment: This is very unclear. Show us the code that you're executing, tell us where the characters are printed (console, webapp, Swing app?)

Comment: Java uses unicode anyway, why change it to UTF-8? Where and what exactly is displayed incorrectly?

Comment: Be more specific. Java handles all Strings as Unicode internally. Are you trying to read from file/stdin ? Are you trying to write to file/stdout ?

Comment: Do you mean that you try to review your source code using Notepad?

Comment: Be sure to tell us what the encoding of the text file is, and to show us the code reading this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations, I also use UTF-8 for my projects, which seems best.

Simply make sure that editor and compiler use the same encoding. This ensures that string literals in java are correctly encoded in the jar, .class files.

In NetBeans 7.3 there is now one setting (I am using maven builds).

Properties files are historically in ISO-8859-1 or encoded as `\uXXXX`. So there you have to take care.

Internally Java uses Unicode, so there might be no other problems.

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputfilepath);
```

should be

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(inputfilepath), "UTF-8")));
```

The same procedure (explicit extra encoding parameter) for FileWriter (OutputStreamWriter + encoding), String.getBytes(encoding), new String(bytes, encoding).

Comment: perfect. Thx. I used the same Codeline, just before reading your post. I changed the Inputencoding and it worked fine in the runnable jar.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 as JVM argument.

Comment: how can I do that? Can you give me an example pls?

Comment: i had actually written this before your edit... if you are reading from text file the files themselves have to be utf-8 encoded. while reading from files pass UTF8 to InputStreamReader

Comment: as for your question, it would be

Comment: as for your question, it would be some thing like java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar yourjarfile